# Could NOT find pocketsphinx (missing: pocketsphinx_DIR)

Tags: python-2.7, ros, pocketsphinx, catkin

I am trying to setup **gaitech_edu** ROS package in order to build a turtlebot line follower. But, when I am trying to compile the package using **catkin_make**, I am getting following error:

[image]

I installed pocketsphinx library for python 2.7 using

`pip install pocketsphinx`.

But, even after that I am getting the same error. I am using ros melodic and python version is 2. Your help/advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem using [this](https://github.com/Pankaj-Baranwal/pocketsphinx) ros package for pocketsphinx.